# Javascript OOP - declaring methods of an object

Tags: javascript, oop

This is the most basic JS object example I can think of that illustrates my questions.

**Question 1.**

How can I reference functions within a class so that in other code I could call a method? This gives me an error.

```
  var name1 = new Name();
  name1.render();
```

**Question 2.**

What is the difference between declaring functions in-line like this vs. using `var getByID = function() ...`?

**Example object:**

```
function Name(user_id, container_id) {
  this.userID = user_id;
  this.containerID = container_id;
  this.firstName = null;
  this.lastName = null;

  function getByID(userID) {
    // An ajax call that takes a userID to get a name.
  }

  function setName() {
    // An ajax call to get the name from db.
    name_record = this.getByID(this.userID); ????? this returns an error that getByID is undefined.
    this.firstName = name_record.firstName;
    this.lastName = name_record.lastName;
  }

  function render() {
    $(this.containerID).val(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass some parameters to `Name`.  `container_id` is `undefined`, so `$(this.containerID)` won't work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: Question 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: P.S. Don't just say "This gives me an error", show us the ***exact error***.

Comment: with sample code provided this.userID would be undefined because you didn't pass any vaue for it to the constructor. It could be a problem with the `this` context. Maybe you should check this answer that explains about prototype and the value of `this` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an object like you done in your second question, it's valid because a function **is** an object too. Or other ways like:

```
var Name = {
    render: function() {
    }
}

Name.render();
```

Or with [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype):

```
function Name() {
}

Name.prototype.render = function() {
}
// or
Name.prototype = {
    getByID: function() {
    },
    setName: function() {
    }
}
var n = new Name();
```

All these snipets are a valid object declaration.

Your second question may answer the first ones. When you declare a function like this:

```
function Name() {
    function render() {
    }
}
var n = new Name();
```

It is like `render()` be a private method. if you call outside the function name `n.render()`, you will see an error thrown because `render` is not recognized. But if you change to this...

```
function Name() {
    this.render = function() {
    }
}
```

... then `n.render()` will work like `render()` being a public method. See [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) and [this](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html) for further information about `public` and `private` methods.

Now, the difference between declaring a function "in-line" or setting it to a variable is that with this:

```
function Name() {
}
```

You can do:

```
var n1 = Name();
var n2 = Name();
var nn = Name(); // and so on...
```

But with:

```
var n = function Name() {
}
```

Is that `n()` will work and `Name()` will not. Even `var a = Name()` will throw an exception.

[Here's a good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) about this subject that worth a read. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
A "Class" in Javascript is nothing more than an object.  An object has properties which you can access.  Those properties are either variables, functions, or other objects.  By declaring your function like:

```
  function render() {
    $(this.containerID).val(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
  }
```

You are declaring a function within the scope of function Name() but that function isn't a property of Name.  It's just a private method.  There are multiple ways you could make it a part of Name(), such as:

```
function Name(user_id, container_id) {
  this.userID = user_id;
  this.containerID = container_id;
  this.firstName = null;
  this.lastName = null;
  this.render = function() {
    console.log('hello world');
  }
}

var name1 = new Name();
name1.render();
```

**Question 2:**
There is no difference.  They are simply two different syntax's that achieve the same result.  The second way (declaring a var and defining the function) immediately gives you a reference to the function, but that can be achieved just as well the first way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question:

Functions getByID,setName and render are local to the constructor and cannot be called by class object. You have to use prototypal inheritance.

for eg.

```
function Name(user_id, container_id) {
this.userID = user_id;
this.containerID = container_id;
this.firstName = null;
this.lastName = null;
}

Name.prototype = {

getByID :function(userID) {
  // An ajax call that takes a userID to get a name.
}

setName:function() {
  // An ajax call to get the name from db.
  name_record = this.getByID(this.userID); 
  this.firstName = name_record.firstName;
  this.lastName = name_record.lastName;
}

render:function() {
  $(this.containerID).val(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
}
};
```

Answer to your second question:

in case of
    abc();//Error
    function abc(){
    }

this function is created at run time , so you can call it only after declaration

however, this

```
abc();
var abc = function(){
};
```

is created at parse time so you can call it before declaration.